# Merge sort optimization and improvement

Tags: c++, optimization, algorithm, mergesort

How to optimize this merge sort code to make it run faster? And how to call `merge_sort` function without user input by declaring necessary array in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int a[50];
void merge(int,int,int);
void merge_sort(int low,int high)
{
int mid;
if(low<high)
{
 mid = low + (high-low)/2; //This avoids overflow when low, high are too large
  merge_sort(low,mid);
  merge_sort(mid+1,high);
  merge(low,mid,high);
 }
}
void merge(int low,int mid,int high)
{
  int h,i,j,b[50],k;
  h=low;
  i=low;
  j=mid+1;

  while((h<=mid)&&(j<=high))

  {
   if(a[h]<=a[j])
  {
   b[i]=a[h];
   h++;
    }
  else
  {
   b[i]=a[j];
   j++;
   }
   i++;
  }
  if(h>mid)
 {
   for(k=j;k<=high;k++)
  {
   b[i]=a[k];
   i++;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  for(k=h;k<=mid;k++)
   {
   b[i]=a[k];
   i++;
   }
  }
  for(k=low;k<=high;k++) a[k]=b[k];
}
int main()
 {
 int num,i;

 cout<<" MERGE SORT PROGRAM"<<endl;

 cout<<endl<<endl;
 cout<<"Please Enter THE NUMBER OF ELEMENTS you want to sort [THEN PRESSENTER]:"       <<endl;
  cin>>num;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Now, Please Enter the ( "<< num <<" ) numbers (ELEMENTS) [THEN PRESS      ENTER]:"<<endl;
 for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
 {
  cin>>a[i] ;
  }
  merge_sort(1,num);
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"So, the sorted list (using MERGE SORT) will be :"<<endl;
  cout<<endl<<endl;

 for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
 cout<<a[i]<<"  ";

cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
return 1;
```

}

Comment: Pretty sure this code is broken: `if(low<high)`

Comment: Clean up your indentation (be consistent and use a number greater than 1). This code is nearly impossible to read as is.

Answer (score 3):

[Dont't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065):

```
 using namespace std;
```

Also why the extra space?

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
^ ?????? Make it look untidy.
```

Global variables are a bad idea.

```
int a[50];
```

Pretty sure this makes the code broken.

```
if(low<high)
```

You don't need to do any more sorting if the size of the array is 0 or 1. Both these sizes of array are already sorted so you can stop.

Don't think that comment is necessary

```
mid = low + (high-low)/2; //This avoids overflow when low, high are too large
```

Also since the maximum size of your array is `50` that is never going to be a problem.

If you are using C++ idiom where ranges as specified from beginning to one past the end then this looks really funky.

```
  merge_sort(low,mid);
  merge_sort(mid+1,high);
```

I would expect it to be:

```
  merge_sort(low, mid);
  merge_sort(mid, high);
```

Also add some more white space between your punctuation (it makes it easier to read). How many books have you read where there is no space after a punctuation mark?

Declare one variable per line please.

```
  int h,i,j,b[50],k;
```

You can declare and initialize them at the same time you. In fact you should.

```
  h=low;
  i=low;
  j=mid+1;
```

Also your names are very bad. They convey no meaning. You are breaking the principle of self documenting code. Its very hard to optimize code. It is even harder to optimize code that is hard to read. Make the code easier to read with nice variable names.

Since I can't read the following because of the crappy indentation. All I am going to say is fix the indentation. And use a size of greater than 1 (at least 2 preferably 4).

```
  while((h<=mid)&&(j<=high))

  {
   if(a[h]<=a[j])
  {
   b[i]=a[h];
   h++;
    }
  else
  {
   b[i]=a[j];
   j++;
   }
   i++;
  }
  if(h>mid)
 {
   for(k=j;k<=high;k++)
  {
   b[i]=a[k];
   i++;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  for(k=h;k<=mid;k++)
   {
   b[i]=a[k];
   i++;
   }
  }
  for(k=low;k<=high;k++) a[k]=b[k];
}
```

Prefer '\n' to `std::endl`

```
 cout<<" MERGE SORT PROGRAM"<<endl;
```

Again more space between your operators.

cout<

> And how to call merge_sort function without user input by declaring necessary array in the code?

To get dynamically sized user data you need a dynamically sized container. `std::vector` is your friend.

```
std::vector   data(size); // is an array of `size` elements.
```

This tells the operating system that your application failed.

```
return 1;
```

return 0 to indicate that the application did not crash. Any other number is an indication that the application did not run as expected.